How can I remove the GlassBackgroundEffect from NavigationStack
Doesn't matter what I do, it's impossible to remove the background color from NavigatonStack.
WindowGroup(id: "main") {
        NavigationStack {
            Color.clear.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(width: 2500.0, height: 1024.0)
        .background(Color.clear)
        .glassBackgroundEffect(displayMode: .never)
        .presentationBackground(.clear)
    }
    .windowStyle(.plain)
    .windowResizability(.contentSize)
}

result: 
Any idea?
Xcode: Version 15.3 (15E204a)
VisionOS: 1.1

By my reading of .glassBackgroundEffect() documentation, what you're doing ought to work. Please file a Feedback with Apple. I might start by removing all of the modifiers except .glassBackgroundEffect, and moving it around. What happens if you use something other than NavigationStack as the root view?

@HalMueller anything but this works as expected.
